# It is possible to always show all tooltip in Chartjs 3.1

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I want to show all tooltip always (not only hover), so that when i download it as pdf i can see the tooltip data. I used chartjs 3.1. it is possile?

[image: Please see the picture.]

Comment: With default tooltip from chartJS, it won't be possible, as tooltip serve different purpose on the web page irrespective of chart or input element. So it is not possible to show all the tooltip. But yeah you can design your own component and show all of them together before printing same like toogle a html div with data

Answer (score 0):

If you want all datapoints you cant use the tooltip for that, you will have to use the datalabels plugin for that: https://v2_0_0-beta_1--chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/samples/charts/line.html

If you only want to show 1 datapoint with the tooltip on download you can programaticatlly trigger the tooltip like so:

```js
var options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderWidth: 1
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderWidth: 1
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {}
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(ctx, options);

document.getElementById("triggger").addEventListener("click", () => {
  const tooltip = chart.tooltip;
  if (tooltip.getActiveElements().length > 0) {
    tooltip.setActiveElements([], {
      x: 0,
      y: 0
    });
  } else {
    const chartArea = chart.chartArea;
    tooltip.setActiveElements([{
      datasetIndex: 0,
      index: 2,
    }, {
      datasetIndex: 1,
      index: 2,
    }]);
  }

  chart.update();
});
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <br>
  <button id="triggger">
      trigger hover
    </button>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.2.0/chart.js" integrity="sha512-opXrgVcTHsEVdBUZqTPlW9S8+99hNbaHmXtAdXXc61OUU6gOII5ku/PzZFqexHXc3hnK8IrJKHo+T7O4GRIJcw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```